# Vagrant won't sync its parent folder on host

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, puphpet

I am running Vagrant on Windows 8.1 using Puphpet. Using following sync settings:

```
source: ../
target: /var/www/myserver
sync_type: default
```

As far as I know ../ should sync the parent folder of the vagrant, but its syncing the same folder its in.

EDIT: Let's say I have folder structure like /folder1/folder2 and here I have vagrantfile folder1/folder2/Vagrantfile now I wanted to sync the folder1. It doesn't matter if I have ./ or ../ folder2 will be synced. I want to sync the parent folder (folder1).

How can I sync the parent folder of the vagrant file?

Answer (score 0):

All directories use the location of the `Vagrantfile` as the base:

https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/blob/master/src/Puphpet/Extension/VagrantfileLocalBundle/Resources/views/Vagrantfile.rb.twig#L3

`dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))`

To share the actual directory containing your `Vagrantfile` (and everything within), use `./`.

Comment: I am sorry I think I wasn't clear enough. Let's say I have folder structure like /folder1/folder2 and here I have vagrantfile folder1/folder2/Vagrantfile now I wanted to sync the folder1. It doesn't matter if I have ./ or ../ folder2 will be synced. I want to sync the parent folder (folder1). Is this possible?